# How do I script a bunch of Gnome appearance changes?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

On installing Ubuntu 18.04 one of the first things I do is install `gnome-tweaks` and change these settings:

- Appearance > Themes > Applications
- Appearance > Background > Image
- Appearance > Lock Screen > Image
- Desktop > Home > off
- Desktop > Network Servers > off
- Keyboard & Mouse > Mouse > Acceleration Profile > Flat
- Workspaces > Static Workspaces

Supposing I wanted the setup of a new machine to be fully scripted. How would I make the same changes in a script? In which files are all these things stored?